# Heroku Postgres: Too many connections. How do I kill these connections for TEAM/ORGANIZATION?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli, data-connections

I needed to find an answer to it and wasn't able to, so I decided to share it with you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Heroku CLI on your machine.

Authorize using `heroku login` . After type

```
heroku apps -t team-name
```

After you'll see apps on your team. Copying the app name we need

```
heroku pg:killall --app appName
```

We paste the app name we need. Congrats you have killed all yours connections.